# UITextView issue with ActionSheetStringPicker Picker view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

[image: Here are the screenshots.]

Check 3 screenshots here first.

Screenshot 1 : Subject is UITextview field. When I tap on subject text field normal keyboard will come. There is no problem here now.

Screenshot 2 : Priority is UITextfield view. Here I use UIActionsheet Picker view. When I click on Priority textfield picker will appear as shown in screenshot. This is also working fine.

**My Problem** : When I click Priority textfield directly from Subject textview by scrolling without using done button or next button from keyboard. Then following issue is arriving.

or when I move UITextview to other any other Text Field like in Help Topic Text Field or Source Text Field (In this text field UIActionsheet is used.) same problem is arriving.

See screenshot number 3.

here, keyboard and UIActionsheet both are appearing. Here keyboard is not hiding, it is still appearing. It will not appear here, when I move here UITextView to next Text Field i.e in UIActionsheet picker, it has show Picker VIew only.

What is the problem I am not getting. Anybody please tell me solution for that.

Here is some code for that,

```
@interface EditDetailTableViewController ()
{
    NSNumber *help_topic_id;
    NSNumber *priority_id;



    NSMutableArray * pri_idArray;
    NSMutableArray * helpTopic_idArray;
}

- (void)helpTopicWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element;
- (void)priorityWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element

- (void)actionPickerCancelled:(id)sender;
@end

@implementation EditDetailTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];


    help_topic_id=[[NSNumber alloc]init];
    priority_id=[[NSNumber alloc]init];
}

-(void)removeKeyBoard
{
    [self.subjectTextView resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)priorityClicked:(id)sender {
    [_priorityTextField resignFirstResponder];

    if (!_priorityArray||![_priorityArray count]) {
        _priorityTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
        priority_id=0;

    }else{
        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Priority" rows:_priorityArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(priorityWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
    }

}

- (IBAction)helpTopicClicked:(id)sender {
    [_helpTopicTextField resignFirstResponder];

    if (!_helptopicsArray||!_helptopicsArray.count) {
        _helpTopicTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
        help_topic_id=0;
    }else{
        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Helptopic" rows:_helptopicsArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(helpTopicWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
    }

}

- (void)priorityWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
    priority_id=(pri_idArray)[(NSUInteger) [selectedIndex intValue]];

    //self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];

    //may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
    self.priorityTextField.text = (_priorityArray)[(NSUInteger) [selectedIndex intValue]];
}

- (void)helpTopicWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element {
    help_topic_id=(helpTopic_idArray)[(NSUInteger) [selectedIndex intValue]];
    // self.selectedIndex = [selectedIndex intValue];

    //may have originated from textField or barButtonItem, use an IBOutlet instead of element
    self.helpTopicTextField.text = (_helptopicsArray)[(NSUInteger) [selectedIndex intValue]];
}


#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

if (textField.tag==1) {

        [_priorityTextField resignFirstResponder];
         _priorityTextField.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        if (!_priorityArray||![_priorityArray count]) {
            _priorityTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
            priority_id=0;

        }else{

            [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Priority" rows:_priorityArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(priorityWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:self.view];
        }

        // return NO;
    }else if(textField.tag==2){
        //[_subjectTextField resignFirstResponder];
        [_helpTopicTextField resignFirstResponder];
         _helpTopicTextField.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        if (!_helptopicsArray||!_helptopicsArray.count) {
            _helpTopicTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
            help_topic_id=0;
        }else{
            [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Helptopic" rows:_helptopicsArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(helpTopicWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:self.view];
        }
        // return NO;
    }else{

    }
    // return YES;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}


- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    //[textView resignFirstResponder];

    if(textView == _subjectTextView)
    {

        if([text isEqualToString:@" "])
        {
            if(!textView.text.length)
            {
                return NO;
            }
        }

        if([textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text].length < textView.text.length)
        {

            return  YES;
        }

        if([textView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:text].length >100)
        {
            return NO;
        }

        NSCharacterSet *set=[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890 "];


        if([text rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound)
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }


    return YES;
}




@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following `IBAction` code:

```
- (IBAction)staffClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (!_staffArray||!_staffArray.count) {
        _assignTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
        staff_id=0;
    }else{

        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Select Assignee",nil) rows:_staffArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(staffWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
    }
}
```

... and the following methods:

```
- (void)staffWasSelected:(NSNumber *)selectedIndex element:(id)element
{
    staff_id=(staff_idArray)[(NSUInteger) [selectedIndex intValue]];
    self.assignTextField.text = (_staffArray)[(NSUInteger) [selectedIndex intValue]];
}


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
}
```

... will solve your problem for you.

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to SO, and thanks for answering a question!  Could you please edit your question to include a brief explanation in English of what your code does / what it fixes?  In other words, what was wrong with the code in the question, which you fixed in your solution?  Thanks!

Comment: this is perfect answer for me..! Thank you..!

Comment: In this method, she made a mistake - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField .

Comment: she was using - (IBAction)staffClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    if (!_staffArray||!_staffArray.count) {
        _assignTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
        staff_id=0;
    }else{

        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Select Assignee",nil) rows:_staffArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(staffWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
    }
}

Comment: this method as well as . also she written code in - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField. So that, we she click in text field then cursor comes to textFieldDidBeginediting menthod, even she written action for it . So, here she is using multiple text fields, thwn when she click on textfield, then picker will appear as well as keyboard was appearing but to method of textFieldDidBeginEditing. So, that method need to be remove and have to use  - (IBAction)staffClicked:(id)sender only.

Comment: It will work. nd for hiding keyboard or if you do not want to show keyboard after clicking a uitextfield - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    return NO;
} this method have to use...! this is solution..!

Comment: @MaxvonHippel it is works for me...! whatever Mallikarjun answered, i done some thing. I works for me..!

Comment: That's good to hear @Shrutikadam, but generally it's better to include an explanation, too, so people who read this in the future can better understand the answer. Also, please consider using [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to make the code blocks in your comments more readable in the future.  I'm definitely glad that this answer solved your problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of timing issue Action picker will take some time to reload picker on keyboard

BTW you should change your code here And also implement same in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
- (IBAction)priorityClicked:(id)sender {
    [_priorityTextField resignFirstResponder];

    if (!_priorityArray||![_priorityArray count]) {
        _priorityTextField.text=NSLocalizedString(@"Not Available",nil);
        priority_id=0;

    }else{
        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Priority" rows:_priorityArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(priorityWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];
    }

}
```

In the **else** part you should call `showPickerWithTitle` method after some delay like below

```
else{
  [self performSelector:@selector(openPickerWithDelay:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.5]; // Change 0.5 to whatever you want.

}
```

Add new method

```
-(void) openPickerWithDelay:(id) sender {
        [ActionSheetStringPicker showPickerWithTitle:@"Select Priority" rows:_priorityArray initialSelection:0 target:self successAction:@selector(priorityWasSelected:element:) cancelAction:@selector(actionPickerCancelled:) origin:sender];

}
```

**Otherwise you can delay by**

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.5; // Change 0.5 to whatever you want.
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

// Do your stuff here

});
```

Comment: still keyboard is not hiding. Still it is appearing. Both are working fine independently. Only problem came when, I move and tap subject textview to directly to Priority textfield.

Comment: First you should write code for hide already opened keyboard of textfield after it will be work

Comment: Put just write one line code [self.view endEditing:YES];
 for hide keyboard

Comment: where I add [self.view endEditing:YES]; this code in my code