# Anybody is getting UI issues after updating xcode 9 and iOS 11.0?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

When I updated my xcode and ios 11.0 ...Some UI changed. I mean there alignment and positions.

One serious issue is coming in my project is that, keyboard is not hiding.
**Scenario is**  Suppose I am typing something in UITextfield and move to next UITextfield. Here in second UITextfield I used UIActionSheet pickerview. So, when i click on second UITextfield then UIActionSheet pickerview is coming as well as previous keyboard is not hiding. UIActionSheet picker is showing back of keyboard and keyboard is not hiding.

See the above Image.

[image: Here is the Screenshots.]

I already posted this issue here,
[UITextView issue with ActionSheetStringPicker Picker view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520850/uitextview-issue-with-actionsheetstringpicker-picker-view/46521065?noredirect=1#comment79996399_46521065)

Comment: The things is you should write the coding for hidding the keyboard when you click textFiled of UIActionSheet PickerView

Comment: @iPatel already I tried   [self.view endEditing:YES]; this code, but still getting that issue.

Comment: There's some issue in the simulator in Xcode9, I've also noticed but the apps are working fine on real devices.

Comment: is it working in Xcode 8 ? and if possible than check in real device with iOS 11

Comment: @Nirav  The thing is that, whatever this issue is coming after updating iOS 11.0 and xcode 9. Before updating iOS 11.0 it was working fine and before updating my xcode and iOS 11.0 I was uploaded my new code on App store (I made a release.) that time it was working fine, this issue was not there not time. And after release most of my friends downloaded that App from App store that time also that issue not came, that time his mobile had iOS 10 os. Then when he updated to iOS 11.0 then that issue was started as well as When I updated xcode and my iPad to iOS 11.0 that issue is coming.

Comment: If the issue was in code then it has to come at time when I prepared a App for release on App. That time i was using xcode 8.3.3 and my iOS Version was 10.0 something. So that time, it was working fine. So our tester tested my app and then I uploaded on App Store. So, when before iOS 11.0 release it was working fine, after updating iOS 11.0 that issue is coming.

Comment: I checked with real device in iPhone 8+ with iOS 11.0.2 os.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextView issue with ActionSheetStringPicker Picker view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520850/uitextview-issue-with-actionsheetstringpicker-picker-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

again same question..! I already given solution for this question. Check below link, 
[UITextView issue with ActionSheetStringPicker Picker view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520850/uitextview-issue-with-actionsheetstringpicker-picker-view)

Comment: Yes...! I saw your answer..!

Answer (score 0):

Here my answer

```
#pragma mark - UITextField Delegate methods

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField isEqual:txtFldActionSheetPicker]) {
       [textField resignFirstResponder];
       return NO;
    }
    else
       return YES;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
   [textField resignFirstResponder];
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: let me check this solution.